# .net Mirrored databases and connection pools

Tags: .net, database, connection-pooling

I am intrested in using the .net Principal/Mirror database in my connection string.

I wanted to ask, what happends with the pooled connections in case of a failover?
Are they terminated?

Answer (score 1):

To give you a detailed idea on what happens have a read here

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms175484.aspx
- http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-130-in-flight-transactions-continue-after-a-failover/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup.aspx

In short once you add that Failover Partner in your connection string the magic happens on the driver and the SQL Server.  This means the driver makes sure that your application is pointed to the correct database and SQL Server makes sure any transactions pending the queue are written to the mirror (which becomes the primary on failover) before it becomes the primary.

That does not give you assurance that the data is completely saved you still need to do something on your code and enclose everthing on a transaction so it rolls back when the process is not completed.

Comment: Link one doesn't mention pooling.

Link two is enlightening, but in flight transactions are out of the pool.

The 3rd link prompted me to add the bounty. Scenario #5 implies that connection pooling and mirroring don't mix, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yeah I agree it doesn't make sense the driver should be smart enough to reset the information based on the current principal and mirror.  Anyways to handle this is by a try catch block and try to connect again which resets the cache and get a new pool.